# Finding the consecutive zeros in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7,0,10,11]
```

I would like to find the start and the end index of the array where the values are zeros consecutively. For the array above the output would be as follows

```py
[3,8],[12,15],[19]
```

I want to achieve this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Why down vote, Please write the resaon

Comment: It wasn't me but it's traditional to say something like "I have this code" (and show it) and it doesn't quite work. You haven't shown what you've tried.

Comment: well, i can just go through the array with a loop and mark the start and end indices, I thought people who know python would understand it easily

Comment: If pure Python is an option then you can use `itertools.groupby` for this.

Comment: For the record, that syntax doesn't construct an `array` but a `list`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here's a fairly compact vectorized implementation.  I've changed the requirements a bit, so the return value is a bit more "numpythonic":  it creates an array with shape (m, 2), where m is the number of "runs" of zeros.  The first column is the index of the first 0 in each run, and the second is the index of the first nonzero element after the run.  (This indexing pattern matches, for example, how slicing works and how the `range` function works.)

```
import numpy as np

def zero_runs(a):
    # Create an array that is 1 where a is 0, and pad each end with an extra 0.
    iszero = np.concatenate(([0], np.equal(a, 0).view(np.int8), [0]))
    absdiff = np.abs(np.diff(iszero))
    # Runs start and end where absdiff is 1.
    ranges = np.where(absdiff == 1)[0].reshape(-1, 2)
    return ranges
```

For example:

```
In [236]: a = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7, 0, 10, 11]

In [237]: runs = zero_runs(a)

In [238]: runs
Out[238]: 
array([[ 3,  9],
       [12, 16],
       [19, 20]])
```

With this format, it is simple to get the number of zeros in each run:

```
In [239]: runs[:,1] - runs[:,0]
Out[239]: array([6, 4, 1])
```

It's always a good idea to check the edge cases:

```
In [240]: zero_runs([0,1,2])
Out[240]: array([[0, 1]])

In [241]: zero_runs([1,2,0])
Out[241]: array([[2, 3]])

In [242]: zero_runs([1,2,3])
Out[242]: array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)

In [243]: zero_runs([0,0,0])
Out[243]: array([[0, 3]])
```

Comment: any way to do that with pandas ?

Comment: Nice solution! Is there a reason for using `np.int8` data type in `iszero`?  I think if we simply use booleans we can also avoid `np.abs()` and simply set `absdiff = np.diff(iszero)`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a clever solution. I modified it to count the number of ties in the Mann-Kendall trend test https://stackoverflow.com/a/68442829/2005415

Comment: Oneliner:
`np.ediff1d(np.r_[0, a == 0, 0]).nonzero()[0].reshape(-1, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` to achieve your expected result.

```
from itertools import groupby
a= [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7,0,10,11]
b = range(len(a))
for group in groupby(iter(b), lambda x: a[x]):
    if group[0]==0:
        lis=list(group[1])
        print [min(lis),max(lis)]
```

Comment: This will return `[19, 19]`, I think OP expects just [19]. And instead of creating an unnecessary list `b`, try to use `enumerate(a).`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a custom function, not sure the most efficient but works :

```
def getZeroIndexes(li):
  begin = 0
  end = 0
  indexes = []
  zero = False
  for ind,elt in enumerate(li):
    if not elt and not zero:
      begin = ind
      zero = True
    if not elt and zero:
      end = ind
    if elt and zero:
      zero = False
      if begin == end:
        indexes.append(begin)
      else:
        indexes.append((begin, end))

  return indexes
```