# Find indexes of repeated elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume, I have a NumPy-array of integers, as:

```
[34,2,3,22,22,22,22,22,22,18,90,5,-55,-19,22,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,23,53,1,5,-42,82]
```

I want to find the start and end indices of the array, where a value is more than x-times (say 5-times) repeated. So in the case above, it is the value 22 and 6. Start index of the repeated 22 is 3 and end-index is 8. Same for the repeatening 6.

Is there a special tool in Python that is helpful?
Otherwise, I would loop through the array index for index and compare the actual value with the previous.

Comment: @Evan: I don't think that applies so well: `mode` works on values anywhere in the array, not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: This question is really relevant to any sort of sequence container in python, not just numpy arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `np.diff` and the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24892274/7982275) by @WarrenWeckesser for finding runs of zeros in an array:

```
import numpy as np

def zero_runs(a):  # from link
    iszero = np.concatenate(([0], np.equal(a, 0).view(np.int8), [0]))
    absdiff = np.abs(np.diff(iszero))
    ranges = np.where(absdiff == 1)[0].reshape(-1, 2)
    return ranges

a = [34,2,3,22,22,22,22,22,22,18,90,5,-55,-19,22,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,23,53,1,5,-42,82]

zero_runs(np.diff(a))
Out[87]: 
array([[ 3,  8],
       [15, 22]], dtype=int32)
```

This can then be filtered on the difference between the start & end of the run:

```
runs = zero_runs(np.diff(a))

runs[runs[:, 1]-runs[:, 0]>5]  # runs of 7 or more, to illustrate filter
Out[96]: array([[15, 22]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Python's native `itertools`.

Code

```
import itertools as it


def find_ranges(lst, n=2):
    """Return ranges for `n` or more repeated values."""
    groups = ((k, tuple(g)) for k, g in it.groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[-1]))
    repeated = (idx_g for k, idx_g in groups if len(idx_g) >=n)
    return ((sub[0][0], sub[-1][0]) for sub in repeated)


lst = [34,2,3,22,22,22,22,22,22,18,90,5,-55,-19,22,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,23,53,1,5,-42,82]    
list(find_ranges(lst, 5))
# [(3, 8), (15, 22)]
```

Tests

```
import nose.tools as nt


def test_ranges(f):
    """Verify list results identifying ranges."""
    nt.eq_(list(f([])), [])
    nt.eq_(list(f([0, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 2], 5)), [(1, 6)])
    nt.eq_(list(f([1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2, 1, 3, 1,1,1,1,1,1], 5)), [(0, 5), (10, 15)])
    nt.eq_(list(f([1,1, 2, 1,1,1,1, 2, 1,1,1], 3)), [(3, 6), (8, 10)])    
    nt.eq_(list(f([1,1,1,1, 2, 1,1,1, 2, 1,1,1,1], 3)), [(0, 3), (5, 7), (9, 12)])
    
test_ranges(find_ranges)
```

This example captures (index, element) pairs in `lst`, and then groups them by element.  Only repeated pairs are retained.  Finally, first and last pairs are sliced, yielding (start, end) indices from each repeated group.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336492/4531270) for finding ranges of indices using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on what lambda x: x[-1] does ? Thank you

Comment: `enumerate(lst)` is passing `(index, element_from_lst)` pairs into `groupby()`.  `lambda x: x[-1]` is telling `groupby()`, "group according to the element found in each pair."  It's equiv. to a regular function, e.g `def use_elem(x): return x[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a great short-cut for this.  You can do something like:

```
mult = 5
for elem in val_list:
    target = [elem] * mult
    found_at = val_list.index(target)
```

I leave the not-found exceptions and longer sequence detection to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `value` repeated `n` times in list `L`, you could do something like this:

```
def find_repeat(value, n, L):
    look_for = [value for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i] == value and L[i:i+n] == look_for:
            return i, i+n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively quick, errorless solution which also tells you how many copies were in the run. Some of this code was borrowed from KAL's solution.

```
# Return the start and (1-past-the-end) indices of the first instance of
# at least min_count copies of element value in container l 
def find_repeat(value, min_count, l):
  look_for = [value for _ in range(min_count)]
  for i in range(len(l)):
    count = 0
    while l[i + count] == value:
      count += 1
    if count >= min_count:
      return i, i + count
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. This is what I came up with, using only comprehension lists:

```
A=[34,2,3,22,22,22,22,22,22,18,90,5,-55,-19,22,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,23,53,1,5,-42,82]
```

Find unique and return their indices

```
_, ind = np.unique(A,return_index=True)
```

np.unique sorts the array, sort the indices to get the indices in the original order

```
ind = np.sort(ind)
```

`ind` contains the indices of the first element in the repeating group, visible by non-consecutive indices
Their `diff` gives the number of elements in a group. Filtering using `np.diff(ind)>5` shall give a boolean array with `True` at the starting indices of groups. The `ind` array contains the end indices of each group just after each `True` in the filtered list

Create a dict with the key as the repeating element and the values as a tuple of start and end indices of that group

```
rep_groups = dict((A[ind[i]], (ind[i], ind[i+1]-1)) for i,v in enumerate(np.diff(ind)>5) if v)
```