# ffill with limit in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For performance reasons I'd like to use Numpy to do the same kind of forward fill I can get with Pandas like so:

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 2, nan, nan, nan, 7, 8, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
s.ffill(limit=7)
```

which results in:

```
array([ 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 7., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., nan])
```

I've got a forward fill **without** limit working, but that doesn't do it for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array? It includes a vectorized numpy solution by one of the best numpy question-answerers on this platform.

Comment: @jakub Nope, it does not have the limit I ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Basically combined solutions from these two sources:

- [Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array)
- [Finding the consecutive zeros in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885092/finding-the-consecutive-zeros-in-a-numpy-array/)

and added assignment for indices that are over the threshold limit:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 8, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
limit = 7

mask = np.isnan(arr)
idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.size), False)

# Create an array that is 1 where idx is 0, and pad each end with an extra 0.
isnonzero = np.concatenate(([0], np.equal(idx, 0).view(np.int8), [0]))
absdiff = np.abs(np.diff(isnonzero))

# pair-wise indices for consecutive zero ranges
ranges = np.flatnonzero(absdiff == 1)

# add to_begin padding to get overflow and ranges equal size
overflow = np.ediff1d(ranges, to_begin=0) - limit
overflow_mask = overflow > 0

# do the actual fill
arr = arr[np.maximum.accumulate(idx)]

# reassign overflowed elements to nan
arr[ranges[overflow_mask] - overflow[overflow_mask]] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8., 8., nan])
```

Only tested it with the one given example, so there might be some inconsistency.

**EDIT**

Noticed that this will only set the first exceeding element, so probably not the solution you are looking for. I tried to reshape `ranges` into `(-1,2)` and modify in-place each range on the first axis to be a slice over the corresponding overflow. This does work but i had no luck in trying to assign the 2d slices back to `arr`.

```py
# pair-wise indices for consecutive zero ranges
ranges = np.flatnonzero(absdiff == 1).reshape(-1,2)

overflow = np.diff(ranges) - limit
overflow_mask = overflow > 0
# modify ranges so overflowing ranges is a slice over the corresponding overflow
ranges[None,:,0][overflow_mask.T] = ranges[None,:,1][overflow_mask.T] - overflow[overflow_mask]
```