# Filling parts of a list without a loop

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list or numpy array

```
  ll=[7.2,0,0,0,0,0,6.5,0,0,-8.1,0,0,0,0]
```

and an additional list indicating the positions of non-zeros

```
  i=[0,6,9]
```

I would like to make two new lists out of them, one filling the zeros and one counting in between, for this short example:

```
  a=[7.2,7.2,7.2,7.2,7.2,7.2,6.5,6.5,6.5,-8.1,-8.1,-8.1,-8.1,-8.1]
  b=[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4]
```

Is therea a way to do that without a for loop to speed up things, as the list ll is quite long in my case.

Comment: A loop will be involved in some form or another by necessity, even if it can probably be dressed up in various ways.

Comment: Is this truely a list?  Not a `numpy` array?  Doing stuff to lists without loops is impossible.  'without loop' is a `numpy` goal.  But you need to be careful when using `numpy` solutions - the act of converting a list to array is nontrivial (timewise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array `a` is the result of a forward fill and array `b` are indices associated with the range between each consecutive non-zero element.

pandas has a [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) function, but it should be easy enough to compute with numpy and there are many sources on how to do this.

```
ll=[7.2,0,0,0,0,0,6.5,0,0,-8.1,0,0,0,0]
a = np.array(ll)

# find zero elements and associated index
mask = a == 0
idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.size), False)

# do the fill
a[np.maximum.accumulate(idx)]
```

output:

```
array([ 7.2,  7.2,  7.2,  7.2,  7.2,  7.2,  6.5,  6.5,  6.5, -8.1, -8.1,
       -8.1, -8.1, -8.1])
```

More information about forward fill is found here:

- [Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array)
- [Finding the consecutive zeros in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885092/finding-the-consecutive-zeros-in-a-numpy-array/)

Computing array `b` you could use the forward fill mask and combine it with a single `np.arange`:

```
fill_mask = np.maximum.accumulate(idx)
np.arange(len(fill_mask)) - fill_mask
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
import numpy as np

ll = np.array([7.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.5, 0, 0, -8.1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
i = np.array([0, 6, 9])

counts = np.append(
  np.diff(i),       # difference between each element in i 
                    #    (i element shorter than i)
  len(ll) - i[-1],  # + length of last repeat
)
repeated = np.repeat(ll[i], counts)
```

`repeated` becomes

```
[ 7.2  7.2  7.2  7.2  7.2  7.2  6.5  6.5  6.5 -8.1 -8.1 -8.1 -8.1 -8.1]
```

`b` could be computed with

```
b = np.concatenate([np.arange(c) for c in counts])
print(b)
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4]
```

but that involves a loop in the form of that list comprehension; perhaps someone Numpyier could implement it without a Python loop.